# C# Filestream to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, file, filestream

I want to create a file in SQL Server from a string. I can't figure out how to put it into the database. After reading it seems it has someting to do with filestream. If so then once the stream is created then how do I put that to my DB as a file?

```
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("somefilename", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);

writer.WriteLine("file content line 1");
writer.Close();
```

What I am trying to achieve is create a file from a string. I believe that my db is already set up for files. As we have a savefile method that works:

```
HttpPostedFile file = uploadedFiles[i];
                if (file.ContentLength < 30000000)
                {
                    //DOFileUpload File = CurrentBRJob.SaveFile(CurrentSessionContext.Owner.ContactID, Job.JobID, fileNew.PostedFile);

                    DOFileUpload File = CurrentBRJob.SaveFile(CurrentSessionContext.Owner.ContactID, Job.JobID, file, file.ContentLength, CurrentSessionContext.CurrentContact.ContactID);
                    DOJobFile jf = CurrentBRJob.CreateJobFile(CurrentSessionContext.Owner.ContactID, Job.JobID, File.FileID);
                    CurrentBRJob.SaveJobFile(jf);
                }
```

What I want to do is: Instead of the user selecting a file for us to save to the DB. I want to instead create that file internally with strings and then save it to the db.

Comment: If you want to store a string in SQL Server just store it in a VARCHAR field. If you want to store a file in SQL Server the best way is to use filestream. So the first thing you need to do is configure SQL Server for filestream and add a column to hold your file. Here is one reasonable guide: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/. It's not a trivial exercise though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a a column type of any one below. Use ADO.NET `SqlCommand` write it to database.

- `varbinary(max)` - to write binary data
- `nvarchar(max)` - for unicode text data  (i mean if text involves UNICODE chars)
- `varchar(max)` - for non unicode text data

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. **Avoid using these data types** in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Ya agree, use nvarchar(max), varchar(max). I edited the answer